# Trying to change color of a button pressed from a dynamic list using useRef to uplift the state [React Native]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, use-ref

I am trying to change the color of a button pressed from a dynamic json list using useRef. But when I use the useRef it is only aiming at the last value of the list.But if I add array in the list then how would the main component know which element was pressed ?

[Need to make the background of the selected item colored and rest white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8fuc.png)

**Parent Element**
==> InvoiceTitle is the child component

```js
const Usage = () => {
  const data = UsageDataMock;
  const invoiceTitleRef = useRef("");

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log(
      "Selected Title => ",
      invoiceTitleRef?.current?.getSelectedTitle()
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 50 }}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <InvoiceTitle
          ref={invoiceTitleRef}
          key={item.id}
          title={item.title}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```js
const InvoiceTitle = forwardRef(
  ({ title, onChange, ...props }: InvoiceTitleProps, ref) => {
    const [selectedTitle, setSelectedTitle] = useState("");

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      getSelectedTitle: () => selectedTitle,
    }));
    const onClick = (title: string) => {
      onChange(selectedTitle);
    };
    console.log("default title", selectedTitle);

    return (
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => onChange(setSelectedTitle(title))}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          styles.titleContainer,
          { backgroundColor: "red", opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1 },
        ]}
      >
        <AppText>{title}</AppText>
      </Pressable>
    );
  }
);
```

Updated 28th Nov

Getting selected items but now it is changing color of every button .

```js
const Usage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(UsageDataMock1);
  const invoiceTitleRef = [];

  const onChange = (index, selectedTitle) => {
    // console.log('Selected Title => ', invoiceTitleRef[index].getSelectedTitle())
    const tempSelection = invoiceTitleRef[index].getSelectedTitle();
    const temp = data.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.title == tempSelection) {
        return { ...item, isSelected: "true" };
      } else return { ...item, isSelected: "false" };
    });

    setData(temp);
  };
  console.log("123", data);

  return (
    <AppBackground>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 50 }}>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <>
            {console.log("asd", item)}
            <InvoiceTitle
              ref={(element) => (invoiceTitleRef[index] = element)}
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              selected={item?.isSelected}
              onChange={onChange}
              index={index}
            />
          </>
        ))}
      </View>
    </AppBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 12,
  },
});

export default Usage;
```

**Child Component**

```js
const InvoiceTitle = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      title,
      onChange,
      index,
      key,
      selected = false,
      ...props
    }: InvoiceTitleProps,
    ref
  ) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      getSelectedTitle: () => title,
    }));

    // console.log('ASD title', title, selected)
    // const [color, setColor] = useState('white')

    const [color, setColor] = useState("white");

    const onClick = () => {
      onChange(index, title);
    };

    return (
      <Pressable
        key={key}
        onPress={() => onClick()}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          styles.titleContainer,
          {
            backgroundColor: selected ? "red" : "blue",
            opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <AppText>{title}</AppText>
      </Pressable>
    );
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 12,
  },
});

export default InvoiceTitle;

interface InvoiceTitleProps {
  title: string;
  onChange: Function;
  index: number;
  selected: boolean;
  key?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a single ref to all so it saves only last value and overwrites  all previous ones.
you have to create as many refs as the length of your items

```
  import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default function App() {
  const data = [{name:'wqh',id:12},{name:'dj',id:1212}]
  const invoiceTitleRef = [] //Array of refs 

  const onChange = (index, selectedTitle) => {
    console.log(index, selectedTitle) //you have your index and selected value of the item
    console.log('Selected Title => ', invoiceTitleRef[index].getSelectedTitle())
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50,flex:1,backgroundColor:'green' }}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (

        <InvoiceTitle
          index={index}
          ref={ref => invoiceTitleRef[index]=ref}
          key={item.id} title={item.name}
          onChange={onChange} />
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}

const InvoiceTitle = React.forwardRef(({
    title,
    onChange,
    index,
    ...props
}: InvoiceTitleProps, ref) => {

    const[selectedTitle, setSelectedTitle] = React.useState('')

    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       getSelectedTitle : () => title
    }))
    const onClick = () => {
      setSelectedTitle(title)
      onChange(index,selectedTitle)
    }
  

    return (
        <Pressable 
        onPress={onClick} 
            style = {({pressed}) => [styles.titleContainer,
             {backgroundColor : 'red', opacity : pressed ? 0.5 : 1}]}>
           <Text>{title}</Text>
       </Pressable>
    )
})


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  titleContainer:{
    margin:20,
    padding:20
  }
});
```

**another way :-**
this way you don't need to use ref. you have index and value in your onChange method inside parent component and now you know which item is pressed you can save in array or just use it.(don't need to use any refs )

Comment: Hey could you look into it. I tried and it was not working and I can't figure it out why

Comment: updated. check now. you have to take array of refs and use that

Comment: wow that part is working now. please help me last with this one. When I try to change color of 1 button the color of all buttons changed. I added a isSelected property but it is changing the color of every button.

Comment: I have added the code with the date stamp above, sire please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now. the new property that I was adding isSelected : 'true', I kept the true in string but it had to be Boolean that caused this ordeal not to fix.